# How can I get special price of an ordered product in "sales_flat_order_item" table

Tags: product, orders, price, sales-order

A product which have following prices in catalog has been sold with qty 1:-

```
Price - 65.00 [INR] [Inc. Tax Rs 8.23]
Rate -  51.61 [INR] [Inc. Tax Rs 6.54]
SpecialPrice - 61.75 [INR] [Inc. Tax Rs 7.82]
Cost  - 59.09
```

when I go to table "sales_flat_order_item" and find this item, there following prices are being shown-

```
base_cost - 59.09
price - 53.93
base_price - 53.93
original_price - 61.75
base_original_price - 61.75
tax_percent - 14.5
tax_amount - 7.82
```

Now in this table which column represent **Rate**, **Special Price** and **Price** of product? So I can know what was the selling price of this product.

Answer (score 0):

You can not know the original price of the product or if the product has a sepcial price when it was ordrered. The price saved in database is the `final_price`, in your case the `special_price`.
To simplify when Magento calculate the `final_price` it check the minimal value between `special_price` and `price`.

Comment: thanks for reply @ Mattheo, I searched but there is no column named "final_price" in table "sales_flat_order_item".